# How can I adjust the meta title and description in a Nuxt app when the ssr property is set to false in the nuxt.config.ts file?

Tags: nuxt.js, metadata

I am using Nuxt2.x app for my portfolio. For some reason I need to disable ssr. So I set ssr:false on my nuxt.config.ts file. My nuxt.config.ts file look like this

`export default defineNuxtConfig({

devtools: { enabled: true },
ssr:true,
target:'static',
})`

Now I want to add SEO matter on my other page. Like I have a about.vue page. This is my about.vue page code

`

### This is About Page

Hello Nuxt About Page

```
<a href="/">Index</a> | <a href="/about">About</a> | <a href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
```

useHead({
    title: "About - ToDoApp",
    meta: [{
      name: "description",
      content: "This is Nuxt ToDoApp"
    }]
  })

`

Although I am using useHead method but when I open view page source title tag is not there. But if I set ssr:true in that case its working properly.

Please note that I am also trying vue-meta and  tag also.

Can anyone help?

I am expecting a solution that if I set ssr:false on my nuxt.config.ts file SEO title, description all the thing working properly.